# Let's nix the [nax]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I suggested this tag in early 2013 but by late 2013 Nokia Ad exchange was abandoned. There is currently only a single question marked.

Is there a way to flag a tag that should be deleted?

Comment: Tag your question with [tag:burninate-request] to request a tag deletion. Also, use a punny title. It's a tradition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just removed the tag from [that one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591668/nokia-ad-exchange-ad-tag-on-windows-phone). The system will delete the tag automatically because it has no associated questions.